# C++ run-time behave unexpected way after installing new C++ redistribute package

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

My C++ application was running on windows XP using shared run-time assemblies version 9.0.30729.1. But recently I installed new  C++ redistribute package and it deployed newer version of run-time assemblies version 9.0.30729.6161.

In Winsxs\policies directory this new policy file also deployed by new C++ redistribute package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. -->
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity type="win32-policy" name="policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.ATL" version="9.0.30729.6161" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"/>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.ATL" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"/>
<bindingRedirect  oldVersion="9.0.20718.0-9.0.21022.8" newVersion="9.0.30729.6161"/>
<bindingRedirect  oldVersion="9.0.30201.0-9.0.30729.6161" newVersion="9.0.30729.6161"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

After this new Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable installation my program shows  "This Application Has Failed to Start Because the Application Configuration Is Incorrect" error. But if I delete above policy file it works fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your application's manifest probably has multiple versions of the CRT mentioned. If you could post your application's manifest (open up the compiled binary in a resource editor and copy it out using the clipboard) it would give me more info.